# Load Custom Javascript Instead of External Source

Tags: javascript, linux

I am trying to reverse engineer some javascript code and am struggling to see how things are working.

In order to get a better feel for this I would like to add some console.log() statements and watch a few variables so that I could see what is going on as the code gets executed.

Is there a way to force my page locally to load javascript from my box instead of from the externally hosted site? I essentially want to modify the script and load my modified version when this external page tries to call whatever functions it needs to go through.

I was thinking maybe modify the hosts file so that when my browser goes to look for the external site it redirects to some kind of internal host? I am not quite sure exactly how to do it. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can just download the webpage (`Ctrl-S`), edit the files, and then run the HTML file locally.

Comment: hmmm not exactly working out the way I had hoped, I'll have to keep digging, maybe something funny is happening now that I have it downloaded.

Comment: alright well downloading it at least allowed me to look at things a little differently and I found another way to do what I want to do, thanks!

Comment: you can use scriptable proxy , or , if you just need console.log, add conditional breakpoint with condition `console.log(var) && false`

Comment: What debugger lets you add breakpoints to external files? Do I need to start using chrome for this?